# Google Sheets array formula not working for negative numbers

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, negative-number

I have used this formula so many times and cannot get it to work for values less than zero

Formula: `=ArrayFormula(iferror(index(PayrollSummary!A:A,small(if(PayrollSummary!I:I<0,row(PayrollSummary!I:I)),row(4:4))),""))`

I use this to find the text of one column based on the value of another. It is the `if(PayrollSummary!I:I<0` that is not working, if I change it to less than 1 I get values from 0-1, but not the ones less than 0.

I have checked the formatting on the column, tried number, financial, custom number formats. I have put the `PayrollSummary!I:I` within `VALUE()` I have tried `LTE()`, it will not give be the negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(PayrollSummary!A:A, SMALL(
 IF(PayrollSummary!I:I*1<0, ROW(PayrollSummary!I:I)), ROW(4:4))), ))
```

Comment: Good thought, nope. But I'm getting another < error for a higher number too. It might be the formatting still. Very confused here haha

Comment: I figured it out, it was something with the array row *shrug*